# .net viewstate safe from SQL injection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-injection, viewstate

I am using commandname and commandargument to control sorting (field and direction). How secure is the viewstate from SQL injection.

Comment: Can you please post your SQL statement code?

Comment: If you are sending those command names or arguments to the client, just sanitize that data before it gets executed as SQL and you'll be fine (if that's all, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing values from the ViewState into concatenated SQL, then yes.  However, if you're using [Bind Parameters](http://www.richquackenbush.com/search?q=bind%20parameters) (you are, aren't you?) then you don't have to worry about it.

**Bad:**

```
string sql = "select * from product where name = ' + ProductNameTextBox.Text + '"
```

**Good:**

```
string sql = "select * from product where name = @name"

using(var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{

   SqlParameter param = new SqlServerParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
   param.Value = ProductNameTextBox.Text;

   command.Parameters.Add(param);

   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is where user-entered values are put directly into queries, allowing malicious users to access or damage your database by taking advantage of your security loopholes.  For example, you have a textbox to search, and the value they enter goes inside the actual query.

Unless your command argument is dynamically entered by the user then SQL injection wouldn't be a threat.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using raw SQL, then you are likely using `DataTable` objects, right?  If you are using a DataTable, then you can sort that data after it's pulled from the database using a `DataView` and bind your control to the DataView.  That way, you're not giving user submitted data access to your SQL.  So, in your code you'd do something like this:

```
DataTable dt = GetData(); // pull data from DB with no sort specified
DataView view = dt.DefaultView;  // Get a DataView so you can sort
view.Sort = "Col1, Col2 DESC"; // assemble sort string from your command args
MyControl.DataSource = view;
MyControl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether "put directly into a SQL Query" means they are parameters of a parameterized Query or as literals... if as literals then the answer is NO.